# How to deploy jar file to JBoss EAP comes along with dependencies by maven

Tags: jboss, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I'm struggling with deploying a jar file to JBoss EAP 6. My app depends on some dependencies. I tried to do some hacks such as using maven-jar-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin but neither work. 
By the way, I tried to make the jar file has the structure like this:

```
|-- my-project.jar
    |-- META-INF
        |-- MANIFEST.MF
    |-- <classes>
    |-- lib
        |-- dependency1.jar
        |-- dependency2.jar
```

But I found that definitely not works. Because there is no way a jar can load a jar inside itself.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module for each dependency you need and that is not already included in JBoss modules:

[How to install a module on JBoss AS 7](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7)

Then you need to specify a dependency on your module in the deployment `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`

```
Dependencies: ......
```

See also https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7